# How does ToolTip show Popup on a control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When set a TooltipText on a control, and the tooltip text will be shown when user move mouse on the control. Tooltip will detect MouseEnter or MouseLeave or anything for this purpose?

I want to know how does a Tooltip show Popup on a control?

Assume that I have a user control with name 'UserControlX'. On UserControlX, I put a button and set Dock property to Fill. I add a UserControlX on Form1, add a ToolTip and set a text to this usercontrol. ToolTip will be not shown when user move mouse on control because user is moving mouse on usercontrol's button, not usercontrol, so the tooltip will never show.

Please help me how to solve this problem so that when move mouse on UserControlX, the tooltip will be shown. Thanks.

Comment: can't you put the tooltip on the button instead of the user control ?

Comment: This way work good. However, I don't like using this way. I want to handle directly in UserControlX, specially when UserControlX have a lot of children (controls). Assume that UserControlX have 2 controls Button1 & Button2. When I mouse move on Button1 -> tooltip will be shown, and when mouse move to Button2 -> tooltip will be shown again -> I don't like this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the tooltip displaying on mouse-over is defined within the control's default template. if you view the default template you will likely see a reference to a tooltip in there. If you go further and view the Tooltip's default template, you will see how it is composed as well as what events it listens to.

To answer your question, you could do what Adrian suggests and put the tooltip on the button as well as the parent control.

If you have time to mess around a bit, you COULD try to see if there is a tooltip displayed event or something to that effect for the button, and then simply invoke the parent control's tooltip manually. It could be considered a hack, but worth a try, maybe.